# What happens if you make a gas of magnetic particles

Tags: gas-laws, magnetism

[I was reading todays SMBC](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?id=3668) which asked what happens if you make a gas of magnetic particles

[image: Comic strip]

So what does happen if you make a gas of magnetic particles?

Comment: You mean ferromagnetic? I'm afraid it won't be gas, more like dust cloud maybe.

Comment: What do You understand by "magnetic"?

Comment: Hmm, supposedly this question is unclear unless you provide the background you have of what "magnetic" is. Even so, it would be more appropriate at physics.SE.

Comment: If so please migrate, since the comic doesn't define magnetism I don't know what to say, in the same way asking what happens when you pour water on paper seems self contained and obvious until someone asks what material is the container made out of. Of course the answer may be that a magnetic gas isn't possible

Comment: Oxygen is a gas and it is paramagnetic, so is nitrogenoxide and nitrogendioxide. When talking about forromagnetic properties, that should strictly speaking not possible. Aerosols, like @Mithoron suggested might be the best you can do. However, I think it fits our site, but you might get more attention at physics.se. Let it play out for a while and flag for migration, if you want to try it there.

Comment: This answer with link to supercold lithium wasn't bad but was deleted ;(

Comment: It deepens what you mean by "magnetic". As another comment says air is already 20% paramagnetic because it contains dioxygen. But of you mean ferromagnetic, then it is probably impossible in a *gas* as gases don't have long range structural order. A dispersion of small magnetic particles would not be *gas*.

Comment: @Mithoron The [news from MIT](http://newsoffice.mit.edu/2009/magnetic-gas-0918) mirrored on [phys.org](http://phys.org/news172415470.html) and with special recommendation [Gyu-Boong Jo, *et. al.*, *Science*, **2009**, *325* (5947), 1521-1524.](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/325/5947/1521) Although, I am not 100% convinced we are talking about gasses any more.

Comment: Paramagnetism doesn't sound like what the comic is asking about because it's induced magnetism. The gas isn't really magnetic, so it would be ferromagnetism. In which case the answer to this question appears to be "it would no longer be magnetic"

Comment: It surprises me looking back that people saw a comic and yet still assumed I had something more to it. Suffice to say a magnetic gas could be gaseous iron, which in hindsight the answer would be "nothing would happen as the magnetic domains wouldn't be lined up in a gas". All the calls for clarification kind of ignore that it's literally a scene in a comic

Comment: Also the book the guy is reading on the toilet gives a hint at something, as well as an opportunity to explain why plasma is not a magnetic gas. So many learning opportunities squandered

Answer (score -1):

If you heat up the magnet above Curie temperature (or more drastically just evaporates it), the magnetic spins will be randomly aligned and the magnetic field  is not produced anymore (at higher temperature).

Comment: Hmmm this looks like one of those questions where we could come to a different answer if we considered a gas of marbles. (We note the ideal gas law *works* for marbles in cylinders over a vibrator.)