# Other than ultracold lithium gas, are any ferromagnetic or magnetic gasses known or hypothesized?

Tags: magnetism, chemistry-in-fiction, gas-phase-chemistry

I'm dealing with an interactive work of fiction right now, and one proposal is to combine two types of puzzles with a magnetic gas. I know that fermionic $\ce{^6Li}$, when cooled below $\pu{1 K}$, has shown verifiable ferromagnetic properties, but that is far too cold to be applicable to the work's setting.

(I'm only willing to suspend the user's belief so much.)

I know that on heating above the Curie temperature for a material, magnetic properties dissolve; but what that temperature is varies quite a bit. (I've seen them between $\pu{90 K}$ and $\pu{1400 K}$, which is pretty radical.) Has anyone yet discovered another molecule that remains magnetic in a gaseous phase? Are any of them at least hypothesized?

Comment: Gas, not really, but  plasma has magnetic properties and (non-thermal) may have reasonable temperature.

Comment: @Mithoron That's helpful, thank you! I was kind of hoping to fit it into a party balloon, though. It's something I can follow up on. Do you have any examples, off hand, of large-scale magnetic plasmas?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27230/what-happens-if-you-make-a-gas-of-magnetic-particles https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33994/could-a-magnet-pull-oxygen-out-of-the-air?r=SearchResults&s=1|46.8673